# Como reemplazar datos en un archivo de texto En JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy avanzado un programa el cual en un punto quiero cambiar un dato especifico de este texto.

```
Nako,2003,15,simple,Alan,0

Chatgpt,2001,20,avanzada,Gabo,25

Jarvis,2013,10,media,Yere,4

Kuka,1999,100,simple,Roberto,0

Apao,2000,20,avanzada,Cristobal,20
```

Ejemplo, quería cambiar el "20" de Cristobal a "30", pero cuando lo ponía en practica en el código, lo que hacia este era reemplazar solo el "30", en vez de dejarlo así:

```
Nako,2003,15,simple,Alan,0

Chatgpt,2001,20,avanzada,Gabo,25

Jarvis,2013,10,media,Yere,4

Kuka,1999,100,simple,Roberto,0

Apao,2000,20,avanzada,Cristobal,30
```

A continuación mostrare mi parte del código el cual me provoca los problemas:

```
while(datosIA.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] partesIa = datosIA.nextLine().split(",");
    int numero =0;
    String numeroString = "";
       //ESTE IF HAY QUE MEJORAR LA CANTIDAD IMPORTANTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
    if(eleccion.equals(partesIa[0])) {
        if(partesIa[3].equals("simple")) {
            System.out.println("Esta IA no se puede mejorar la cantidad de mejoras D:");
        }
        else if(partesIa[3].equals("media")) {
            System.out.println("Esta IA tiene como maximo hasta 5 mejoras :) el cual esta ya tiene: " + partesIa[5]);
            System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de mejoras que quiere.");
            int cMejoras = datosMejoras.nextInt();
            if(cMejoras <= 5- Integer.parseInt(partesIa[5])) {
                System.out.println("Se ha cambiado el valor con exito!");
                numero = Integer.parseInt(partesIa[5]) + cMejoras;
                numeroString = String.valueOf(numero);
                sb.append(String.join(",", numeroString));
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("cambios.txt",true);
                fw.write(","+1);
                fw.close();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Dato se excede del limite!");
            }
        }
        else if(partesIa[3].equals("avanzada")) {
            System.out.println("Esta IA se puede mejorar hasta 30 mejoras :D el cual esta ya tiene: " + partesIa[5]);
            System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de mejoras que quiere.");
            int cMejoras = datosMejoras.nextInt();
            if(cMejoras <= 30- Integer.parseInt(partesIa[5])) {
                System.out.println("Se ha cambiado el valor con exito!");
                numero = Integer.parseInt(partesIa[5]) + cMejoras;
                numeroString = String.valueOf(numero);
                sb.append(String.join(",", numeroString));
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("cambios.txt",true);
                fw.write(","+1);
                fw.close();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Dato se excede del limite!");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("ARCHIVO DE TEXTO MALOOO");
        }
    }
    sb.append("\n");
}

datosMejoras.close();
datosIA.close();
scanEleccion.close();

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(datosIAFile);
fw.write(sb.toString());
fw.close();
System.out.println("----------");
Scanner datosIA2 = new Scanner(datosIAFile);

while (datosIA2.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(datosIA2.nextLine());
}

datosIA2.close();
```

Para apoyar al menos este siguiente código me funciono cuando yo quería reemplazar de simple-> media-> avanzada:

```
File datosIAFile = new File("datos_ia.txt");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (datosIA.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] partesIA = datosIA.nextLine().split(",");
    if (eleccion.equals(partesIA[0])) {
        if (partesIA[3].equals("simple")) {
            System.out.println("Se ha mejorado la IA a media :)");
            partesIA[3] = "media";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("cambios.txt",true);
            fw.write(","+1);
            fw.close();
        } else if (partesIA[3].equals("media")) {
            System.out.println("Se ha mejorado la IA a avanzada :D");
            partesIA[3] = "avanzada";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("cambios.txt",true);
            fw.write(","+1);
            fw.close();
        } else if (partesIA[3].equals("avanzada")) {
            System.out.println("No se ha podido mejorar la IA D: (ya que está mejorada al máximo)");
        } else {
            System.out.println("ARCHIVO DE TEXTO MALOOO");
        }
    }
    sb.append(String.join(",", partesIA));
    sb.append("\n");
}

datosIA.close();

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(datosIAFile);
fw.write(sb.toString());
fw.close();
System.out.println("----------");
Scanner datosIA2 = new Scanner(datosIAFile);
while (datosIA2.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(datosIA2.nextLine());
}
datosIA2.close();

datosIA.close();
scanEleccion.close();
```

Ese código me sirvió pero el primero que di no.

Comment: También podrías leer todo el archivo, cargar los datos a una lista, modificarla y luego guardar los datos al archivo.

Comment: Lo pensé pero la cosa es que si me funciono con la parte de abajo y no se por que con la parte de arriba no

Comment: Hola  El Yetaaa, bienvenido, no logro entender cual es la salida esperada y cual la obtenida, podrías aclararlo?, gracias!